# Clearing Scene And Flushing Variables in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, menu, glut, flush

I have made a game in `OpenGL`, and also have added a menu item. when I right click on the `OpenGL` Screen, the menu item is displayed and I have added an option "`Reset Game`" in it. How Can I clear all the variables involved in the game by clicking on this (Any clear or flush function?).

Here is my code

```
glutCreateMenu(menu);
glutAddMenuEntry("Reset Game", 1);

void menu(int item)
{
    switch (item)
    {
    case 1:
        {
            //Adding a function here to clear all the variables    
        }    
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to code up the routine to reset all your variables to their default values.

```
void Reset()
{
    score = 0;
    lives = 3;
    // etc.
}
```

OpenGL doesn't know what these are so you have to do it yourself.